# вставка svg-иконок с текстом под ними

Tags: svg

Как в один блок вставить 9 иконок, чтобы 5 было на одной строке, а 4 на другой?

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: задаю макс ширину блока, но при вставке 6й иконки она не переносится на другую строку, а сжимает остальные

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap`?

Comment: а нужно чтобы перенеслась на другую строку

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!